# IOS Uiwebview does not load the url

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am new in IOS developing app. I would like to load an url via UIwebview. Here is my code

```
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
NSString *fullURL = [@"http://abc.efg.com/imei/ios-" stringByAppendingString:uniqueIdentifier];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
```

The above code does not load url. The white background shows instead.
Did anything wrong? Please suggest

Comment: try hitting he fullURL in safari, does it work?

Comment: http://abc.efg.com/imei/ios- that url you r trying to open? that url is not valid

Comment: change url try to open https://www.google.com url

Comment: I have used this url "https://www.google.co.in/". Same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. First you construct URL, than request and trying to load.

Here as advice - try to set breakpoint just after you call the method

```
[_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
```

and check if your instance of `UIWebView` exists or instead of break point you can just insert to `NSLog(@"My web view is %@", _viewWeb)` - and check if it is not nil.

Inside your method where you want to load url - first create instance of UIWebView
for example

```
-(void)loadUrl
{
UIWebView *webV = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
NSString *fullURL = [@"http://abc.efg.com/imei/ios-" stringByAppendingString:uniqueIdentifier];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

or if you have property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *viewWeb;
```

just make lazy getter in your .m file of view controller

```
-(UIWebView *)viewWeb
{
    if (!_viewWeb)
    {
        _viewWeb = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    }
    return _viewWeb;
}
```

and than call through `self.viewWeb` instead of `_viewWeb`

Comment: I have inserted breakpoint. The specified url  is seen under url tag.

Comment: not URL but _viewWeb ---> your instance of UIWebView

Comment: Yes  U are right. -viewWeb is nil. Please suggest what is wrong ?

Comment: I can not see your code - but check if you bind your webView with IBOutlet or if you create it programmatically - just make a lazy property and call it like 
self.viewWeb

Comment: do you have project on github ?

Comment: No, Sorry I do not have any project on Github.

Comment: I have used this property " @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *viewWeb; ". Is it correct ?

Comment: Yep, it's correct in terms of connections between IB and your controller. Than next, synthesize your property in order to create variable and call it just viewWeb

Answer (score 0):

The code seems correct.
I will suggest, first you check the url you are loading in web view is working perfectly in your browser.

Comment: I have checked the url on a browser, it wors fine.